# not displaying calculation in textview from editview

Tags: android

I am trying to allow people to input hypothetical new loan information in to editText fields. Upon clicking on button "Calculator" I want it to calculate the monthly payment.

Below is the code on the calculator.java page I have.

```
public class AddDebt extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button Home;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_debt);


}
```

This part is for my Menu to switch between my pages (Activities):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.default_menu, menu);

    MenuItem newDebt = menu.findItem(R.id.newDebt);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AddDebt.class);
    newDebt.setIntent(intent1);

    MenuItem About = menu.findItem(R.id.about);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, About.class);
    About.setIntent(intent2);

    MenuItem Calcu = menu.findItem(R.id.Calcu);
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Calculator.class);
    Calcu.setIntent(intent3);

    MenuItem Manu = menu.findItem(R.id.manu);
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, ManuPage.class);
    Manu.setIntent(intent4);
    return true;
}
```

I have "android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"" declared in my .xml on the Calculator button:

```
    public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.calculate:
            EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBalance);
            String myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();
            int myEditBal = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);

            EditText myEdit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRate);
            String myEditValue2 = myEdit2.getText().toString();
            int myEditRate = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue2);

            EditText myEdit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTerm);
            String myEditValue3 = myEdit3.getText().toString();
            int myEditTerm = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue3);
```

Also FYI: I know this is not a valid loan calculation, I'm using it to ensure I get a valid number:

```
            int editMnthlypmt = myEditBal + myEditRate + myEditTerm;

            TextView textMnthlypmt = new TextView(this);
            textMnthlypmt.setText("" + String.valueOf(editMnthlypmt));

        break;
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I can input the data; however, it does not populate the answer in to my TextView field "textMnthlypmt". Any ideas?

Comment: Where you add `textMnthlypmt` this textview to your contentview?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this and I'm not understanding the question/comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textMnthlypmt.setText("" + String.valueOf(editMnthlypmt));
```

Try this...

Comment: why u r convering this to String? Means can't u do 
textMnthlypmt.setText("" + editMnthlypmt);

Comment: have u added text view in your layout...?

Comment: RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
rl.addView(textview);

Comment: here is the button in my layout:

<Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/payment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
        android:text="Calculate" />

Comment: And here is my textview: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMntlypmt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/payment"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/payment"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTerm"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTerm"
        android:text="" />

Comment: TextView textMnthlypmt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textMntlypmt);

Answer (score 0):

check out you xml once again and

use a already declared text view

```
TextView textMnthlypmt = new TextView(this);
```

with this code you are creating a new text view but not putting it on activity.

Comment: to clarify:   
TextView (declared in the .java) = new (declared in the .xml)(this);
??

Comment: You need to add the text view in you layout either in code else in layout xml hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance of `TextView` but you haven't added to parentView...

try like this..

```
TextView textMnthlypmt = new TextView(this);
textMnthlypmt.setText("" + String.valueOf(editMnthlypmt));
parentView.addView(textMnthlypmt);//where parentView is parent layout defined in layout.activity_new_debt
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: parentView is well.. *parent* whereyou want your TextView be appended.. Check in your activity_new_debt.xml and find what is parentLayout. for eg:- if relativeLayout .. then RelaytiveLayout `parentView = (RlaytiveLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);` ...... OR you can simply go for `RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) myEdit .getParent();` assuming you have common relaytiveLayout  parent..